# how check if a specific request was made in the browser with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, request

I have the follow situation:
I need a way to check if a request to a specific https link was made, like I do to check if has a specific Item in the sessionStorage. example:

```
const thereIsTheSession = sessionStorage.getItem('EXAMPLE');
```

How I do this above but with requests ?
**const thereISTheRequest = ???**

Comment: Was made when? Technically, you can provide wrappers for both `fetch` and `xmlHttpRequest`, logging all the requests made through those, but there's no direct method to somehow 'replay' those from native objects.

Comment: the problem: when i click in a button, this button make a request, but the button is dynamic and I can get the button, so I need to get the request that this button does, understand?

Comment: How exactly you "get" this button? Is the link provided via its attributes, or in some other way?

Comment: The site is in a platform here in my country, this platform render a couple of html, one above other, it depends from the user interaction, and the class in this button change every time that he is rendered, so I can't get any of the element from this page. My idea was get the request that this button does so, understand? i can't apply a eventListener to it, sooo i will make something if this specific request was made

Comment: Do you want to check any possible requests that _you_ have made, or, _any_ request by a third party lib or some client messing with your JS?

Comment: Imagine that: this button, that i dont have access, make a request, if i open my devops browser in the network tab, i can see the specific request that the button trigger, what i want is make a logic if this specific request was made i do something

Comment: No, you can't physically access the network tab requests from javascript.

Comment: skara9, there is no way to do something with a kind of interpector of fetch? just to get the url that the request is made?